# R: how do you do row sums based on the grouping from other variables?

Tags: r

Here is the example data:

```
df <- data.frame("ID1" = c("A","A","B","C"), 
            "Wt1" = c(0.8,0.6,0.4,0.5),
            "ID2" = c("B","A","C","B"),
            "Wt2" = c(0.1,0.4,0.5,0.5),
            "ID3" = c("C",NA,"C",NA), 
            "Wt3" = c(0.1,NA,0.1,NA))
```

And I would like to create a columns (vote) in the dataframe which is based on the argmax of wt from the groups of ID1, ID2, ID3. For example, in row 3 of the example data, sum of wt for "B" is 0.4 and sum of wt for "C" is 0.6, so vote = "C".

So the result will be like

```
  ID1 Wt1 ID2 Wt2  ID3 Wt3 vote
1   A 0.8   B 0.1    C 0.1    A
2   A 0.6   A 0.4 <NA>  NA    A
3   B 0.4   C 0.5    C 0.1    C
4   C 0.5   B 0.5 <NA>  NA    C
```

In the case of tie (row 4 in the example), just select any of the ID values.Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: `df[is.na(df)] <- -Inf;df$vote <- df[c(T,F)][cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df[c(F,T)]))]` might work. You'll get factor warnings but it works for the example. Can explain further if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! @PierreLafortune. The solution works and it's very concise... can you explain further?

Comment: You did not specify tie-breakers for same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's very difficult to manipulate tables formatted like this. This is not your desired output but I'm afraid you might be stuck further down the road.

One suggestion is to format the table so that we can easily retrieve information out of it.

Assign id to each observation

```
df$obs <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Then put them in a long format

```
  df1 <- do.call("rbind",lapply(seq(1,6,2),function(x) {df <- df[,c(x: (x+1),7)]; 
colnames(df) <- c("ID","Wt","obs"); df}))
```

Then my skills with `data.frame` are limited so I switch to `data.table` package.

```
dt <- as.data.table(df1)
```

we sum the number of votes by obs and ID

```
dt[,total:=sum(Wt,na.rm=TRUE),.(obs,ID)]
```

Then it's very easy to retrieve the information.

```
dt[,vote:=.SD[which.max(total)],obs]

#dt
#    ID  Wt obs total vote
# 1:  A 0.8   1   0.8    A
# 2:  A 0.6   2   1.0    A
# 3:  B 0.4   3   0.4    C
# 4:  C 0.5   4   0.5    C
# 5:  B 0.1   1   0.1    A
# 6:  A 0.4   2   1.0    A
# 7:  C 0.5   3   0.6    C
# 8:  B 0.5   4   0.5    C
# 9:  C 0.1   1   0.1    A
# 10: NA  NA   2   0.0    A
# 11:  C 0.1   3   0.6    C
# 12: NA  NA   4   0.0    C
```

Comment: Thanks! @DJJ I realized that adding row labels and converting to long format is a very good idea. I can just left join the original table with the result table by obs.